# Traversing through a line in a loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, geometry, computational-geometry

I want to find the crosses of a line (given by the start and end points) with the grid lines (`x=0,1,2,3...` or `y=0,1,2,3,...`). Thus, whether `x` or `y` of the cross points is an integer.

I came up with the following code for finding the cross points of the line given by `5.5,3.5` and `10.5,20.5` points with the grids (lines parallel to `x` and `y` axes).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float ax[2] = {5.0, 10.5}; // x coordinates of start and end points
float ay[2] = {3.5, 20.5}; // y coordinates of start and end points
int l, k = 0;

int main()
{
    if (ax[k] < ax[k + 1])
    {
        for (l = ceil(ax[k]); l < ax[k + 1]; l++)
        {
            printf("%d,%f\n", l, (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) / (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) * l + ay[k] - (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) / (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) * ax[k]);
        }
    }

    if (ax[k] > ax[k + 1])
    {
        for (l = ceil(ax[k + 1]); l < ax[k]; l++)
        {
            printf("%d,%f\n", l, (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) / (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) * l + ay[k] - (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) / (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) * ax[k]);
        }
    }

    if (ay[k] < ay[k + 1])
    {
        for (l = ceil(ay[k]); l < ay[k + 1]; l++)
        {
            printf("%f,%d\n", (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) / (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) * l + ax[k] - (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) / (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) * ay[k], l);
        }
    }

    if (ay[k] > ay[k + 1])
    {
        for (l = ceil(ay[k]); l < ay[k + 1]; l++)
        {
            printf("%f,%d\n", (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) / (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) * l + ax[k] - (ax[k + 1] - ax[k]) / (ay[k + 1] - ay[k]) * ay[k], l);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but I need to get the crosses in order (scanning from the start to the end of the line). I can sort the crosses found, but I think it would be easier to do this in a single loop.

The expected output is

```
5,3.499999
5.161765,4
5.485294,5
5.808824,6
6,6.590909
6.132353,7
6.455883,8
6.779412,9
7,9.681819
7.102942,10
7.426471,11
7.750000,12
8,12.772727
8.073530,13
8.397058,14
8.720589,15
9,15.863635
9.044118,16
9.367647,17
9.691177,18
10,18.954544
10.014706,19
10.338236,20
```

As you can see, the cross points have been found in order of distance from the start point (`5.0,3.5`).

Comment: @klutt crosses of a single line with all grid lines (x=1,2,3...;y=1,2,3...).

Comment: May I ask what `ax[]` and `ay[]` are? Could you add some comments to your code to help us debugging it more efficently? Thank you : )

Comment: @DadiBit sorry for being vague. They are the `x` and `y` coordinates of the line. I updated the question.

Comment: Is the line form (x:5.0;y:3.5) to (x:10.1;y:20.5) that is what I understand. But how can then the desired output contain a point at x:10.352942, that would be beyond the end point of the line, wouldn't it? To the right of the end point by about 0.25. I think the last point listed in the desired output should not be considered a cross between an axis and that line.

Comment: @Yunnosch you're right. That's a mistake. That point shouldn't be on the list. I will check my calculations. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Yunnosch that was a typo. In the code that I ran for calculating the points, I used `x2=10.5` for the test.

Comment: • make two functions f(x) to get y of x coordinate and f_(y) to get x from y coordinate.
• let curPoint = leftmost point, find the next x intersection ( ceil(x) or x+1 if x is int) and next y intersection (ceil if +ve slope and floor if -ve slope), find this y's x using f_(y). take their minimum ( less x ) if both are valid or take the valid one (valid is in range of the line) & call this x : Xm so that ```curPoint = (Xm,f(Xm))``` and repeat till both x and y aren't valid.

Comment: I am sorry if this comes over as nitpicky. But in your own interest (seeing that you sacrificed some points for the bounty) may I propose to triple check the info you provide in the question? I propose to do that by taking pen and millimetre-grid paper and carefully draw the  grid, the line and the resulting crosses. Then double check your calculations of desired result with what the paper results are. I do not require you to post that image, but please confirm that you did that and that the desired result matches the sample data.

Comment: I also propose to make at least a second sample/desired result pair, with backward line direction. This seems necessary to impress on answerers the need to check for special cases. Maybe another sample with vertical line..... It would also be fair towards answerers, to make them aware of the relevant test cases... I mention this, because most uses of `ceil()` seem to indicate a lack of insight.

Comment: @Googlebot, What's the no. of precision points between two successive grid lines. In other words, how may points can be there between x=1, x=2.

Comment: @Fractal You are thinking of `float` vs. `double` or arbitrary precision mechanisms? If you ask a more pointed question the answer by OP is likely more helpful.

Comment: @Yunnosch I appreciate your heed. However, these are just sample output. I ordered them by hand. I added them per request. I didn't follow your complaint about the lack of insight in using `ceil`.

Comment: @Fractal it depends on the line slope. For example, imagine the line between `1.5,0` and 1.5,10`. There are 9 cross points with integer `y`s and `1<x<2`.

Comment: @Googlebot of course, but you can't calculate all the points beyond some precision. Let's assume, the slope is 0 and tell me how many points can there be between x=1, and x=2 for some line equation `y=c`

Comment: @Fractal you're right, but that's not the priority at this stage. In the above example, I started from the point `5,3.5` but the calculation with `float` gave `5,3.499999`. using `double` improves the calculations, but my priority is the idea for the loop now.

Comment: @Fractal Easily answered: None. Or two if you count start and end point and y is integer. OP is only looking for crosses with integer-values for y and x.

Comment: @Fractal sorry I didn't catch your point. As @Yunnosch said, the cross points are only `1,c` and `2,c` for the line `y=c`.

Comment: I have a suggestion: separate the line segment into the 2 components: an x and a y one, just like vectors! The number of points of the segment with at least one int coordinate is less or equal to the sum of the points with a whole coordinate in the components segments. This can help to create an array that can just fit the points.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884200/getting-all-intersection-points-between-a-line-segment-and-a-2n-grid-in-intege), it has some intersting information.

Comment: @Googlebot @Yunnosch. For `y=c` there'll will be infinite points between any two `x` coordinates. Think `c` as an integer. So, my point is that you can't calculate each and every valid point. There has to be an upper bound on the maximum points you want to calculate between two consecutive grid lines (when either `x=c` or `y=c`). I was asking about that maximum value

Comment: @Fractal I'd consider that case to have zero crossing points. It can be discussed wether start and end point should be listed.

Comment: @Yunnosch you missed my point again. If there's a line `y=c` and `c` is an integer, then every point on `x` will be a valid one for our calculation, irrespective of where you start and end on `x`. Because, `y` coordinate is already an integer.

Comment: @Fractal I agree that one of us misses a point here. I think that OP asks about crossing points, not about points which are on an integer axis and on the line. You seem to disagree or to consider both to be the same. This is not  for you and me to clarify, OP should.

Comment: @Yunnosch, Maybe, I misunderstood the problem if OP meant something else. I thought that he was looking for all the points on a line-segment where either of (or both of) `x` or/and `y` are integers.

Comment: @Fractal For the OP to clarify. I focus on "crosses of a line (given by the start and end points) with the grid lines". You seem to (understandably) focus on "x or y ... is an integer".

Comment: @Fractal you have a valid point (which I had not thought of it). The condition I imposed is not complete (I still don't know how to articulate it). When the slope is `0` or `90°`, both `x` and `y` should be integers. Anyhow, your answer works perfectly.

Comment: @DadiBit Many thanks for the link. I really enjoyed reading it and its references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the full solution to your problem.
Let's say we're currently at coordinate`(x,y)`, then we calculate the offsets of next integers from the `x, y` and call them `dx, dy`. Now, the next nearest point will be of the two possible points:

1. (`x+dx`, Some-corresponding-Y) or
2. (SomeX, `y+dx`)

Now our challenge is to find the which one of the closest one. The slope (Dy/Dx) will actually help us find the next nearest one on the line.

If `dx` offset gives the next nearest point on the line, the corresponding offset of `y` coordinate, `dy`, can be calculated by `dy = minv * dx`. Conversely, if `dy` is the offset which is nearest, then we can calculate `dx` with `dx = m * dy`. So, we actually write an `if` statement to find which of the two possible alternatives is the nearest one. That's it. Once we find the next nearest point, we repeat the same process, until we reach the end point. But, beware of the limitations of the floating point calculations below. When `Dx` or `Dy` is nearly equal to 0 then then no.of valid points will become infinite. So, you need to define an upper bound on the maximum points you want to calculate. So, I didn't handle those cases (`Dx ~ 0` or `Dy ~ 0`) in the code below.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <float.h>

float ax[2] = {5.0, 10.5}; // x coordinates of start and end points
float ay[2] = {3.5, 20.5}; // y coordinates of start and end points

double add(double x, double dx)
{
    return x + dx;
}

double sub(double x, double dx)
{
    return x - dx;
}

typedef double (*nextint) (double);
typedef double (*next) (double, double);

int main()
{
    double x, x1, x2, dx, Dx;
    double y, y1, y2, dy, Dy;
    double m = 0, minv = 0;

    bool dirX, dirY;

    nextint nextintx, nextinty;
    next nextx, nexty;

    x1 = ax[0];
    x2 = ax[1];
    y1 = ay[0];
    y2 = ay[1];

    dirX = x2 > x1;
    dirY = y2 > y1;

    // Tries to find the next integer of x/y
    // depending on their direction
    nextintx = dirX ? ceil : floor;
    nextinty = dirY ? ceil : floor;

    Dx = fabs(x2 - x1);
    Dy = fabs(y2 - y1);
    
    if (Dx == 0 && Dy == 0) {
    //Only a single point. Not a line segment
            if (ceil(x1) == x1 || ceil(y1) == y1)
                    printf("%f, %f\n", x1, y1);
            return 0;
    }

    if (Dx && Dy) {
            m = Dy/Dx; // slope
            minv = Dx/Dy; // Inverse of slope
    }

    // Tries to find the next point on x/y depending
    // on their direction (+ve or -ve)
    nextx = dirX ? add : sub;
    nexty = dirY ? add : sub;

    x = x1;
    y = y1;

#define morex(x)  (dirX ? (x <= x2) : (x >= x2))
#define morey(y)  (dirY ? (y <= y2) : (y >= y2))
#define more(x,y) (morex(x)) && (morey(y))

    while (more(x,y)) {
        // dx, dy values track the offsets from
        // current (x, y) coordinates respectively where
        // one of the two (x+dx, m*(x+dx)) or (minv*(y+dy), y+dy)
        // can be the desired coordinates(with integeral x/y)
        dx = fabs(nextintx(x) - x);
        dy = fabs(nextinty(y) - y);

        // We found the required (x,y) pair
        // and update their
        if (dx == 0 || dy == 0) {
            // Print the coordinates
            printf("%f, %f\n", x, y);

            // Possible offset for x/y to get integers
            dx = (dx == 0) ? 1 : dx;
            dy = (dy == 0) ? 1 : dy;
        } 

        // This is the main logic of this program.
        // The next possible pair can occur at either (x+dx, someY)
        // or (someX, y+dy). The below condition essentially checks
        // which is the closest one to the current (x,y) cooridnate.
        if (dx * Dy <= dy * Dx) {
            x  = nextx(x, dx);
            dy = dx * m;
            y = nexty(y, dy);
        } else {
            y = nexty(y, dy);
            dx = dy * minv;
            x = nextx(x, dx);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could implement a `struct point` and perhaps a `struct line_segment` (which stores two `struct point` and has a property for the slope and the vertical offset, like y=ax+b) and a function that takes it as an argument.

Comment: @DadiBit Yeah. That would definitely improve the answer. I'll do it if I get time. Thanks.

Comment: Note that a representation as y=ax+b does not cover vertical lines, which I assume to be an applicable use case for OPs question.

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah I though about it as well. Maybe the ax+by+c=0 one could potentially help, but some of the code should be rewritten for that logic. That's also why I didn't like that when Dx or Dy is equal to 0 it isn't handeled, which doesn't  make any sense. I might copy this code and edit it heavily to fit all cases; Still, it does what OP asked, so it should be accepted if it gets improved a bit more.

Comment: @Yunnosch, @DadiBit, Now added code to handle `Dx=0` and/or `Dy=0` cases

Comment: And OP is satisfied it seems. That is all I wanted to make sure. I started making an answer, but found too much to be guesswork. Have my upvote for daring, caring and sharing. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch, Thanks you for your comments which helped me understand the problem better.